# Notepad++ highligh by enhance anylexer local variables

Tags: notepad

I am preparing my own color highlight file for CNC programs. At first I use USERdefined language, but I have some particular text that I cant mark. Like words end by ":", and others
So I found about the pluggin enhanced any lexer.
Then this particular things can be done easily. for example.

```
0xff33ff =^((?!MSG;?).)\*?:    ; Only mark words end by : (and not MSG or ; on the same line)
```

I want to make something similiar for the local variables that are defined on the header and then use the match string as the word I want to highligh.
thanks¡

```
DEF REAL DIAM  ; I can find it by using (?<=def\sreal\s)\w+
DIAM  = 25 ; I want to mark DIAM
```

I try in enhanceanylexerconfig.ini this

```
test =(?\<=def\\sreal\\s)\\w+

#7fff00  =test
```

but it doesnt work.